# base class using a type defined by the parent class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, mixins

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application where a base class `A_Base` needs to instantiate a data member whose type is defined by a parent class. For example:

```
template< typename T >
class A_Base
{
public: 
    typedef typename T::Foo Bar; // line 10

private:
    Bar bar_;
};

class A : public A_Base< A > 
{
public:
    typedef int Foo;
};

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    A a;
return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it appears the compiler doesn't know what `T::Foo` is until it's too late and I get errors like this:

```
1>MyApp.cpp(10) : error C2039: 'Foo' : is not a member of 'A'
1>        MyApp.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'A'
1>        MyApp.cpp(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'A_Base<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=A
1>        ]
1>MyApp.cpp(10) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Bar'
1>MyApp.cpp(10) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>MyApp.cpp(10) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Is there any way to achieve this type of functionality?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
template< typename T >
class A_Base
{
public: 
    typedef typename T::Foo Bar; // line 10

private:
    Bar bar_;
};

class A_Policy
{
public:
    typedef int Foo;
};

class A : public A_Base<A_Policy>
{};

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    A a;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`A_Base<A>` is instantiated at a point where `A` is not complete yet :

```
class A : public A_Base< A >
```

You could consider using a traits class :

```
template<class T> struct traits;

template< typename T >
class A_Base
{
public: 
    typedef typename traits<T>::Foo Bar; // line 10

private:
    Bar bar_;
};

class A; // Forward declare A

template<> // Specialize traits class for A
struct traits<A>
{
    typedef int Foo;
};

class A : public A_Base< A > {};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `A` depends on class `A_Base` which depends on class `A`... etc. You have a recursion here. You need to declare `Foo` in a separate class.

```
class A;

template<typename T> struct Foo;
template<> struct Foo<A> { typedef int type; };

template< typename T >
class A_Base
{
public: 
    typedef typename Foo<T>::type Bar; // line 10

private:
    Bar bar_;
};

class A : public A_Base< A > 
{
};
```

See also [GotW #79](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm).